# Help with path error when databinding to a dependency property of a class instance

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I'm having some trouble binding to a certain dependency property on a business object in our application.  We have many other bindings in place.  I'm just not sure why this one does not work.

The UserControl XAML looks is basically what is shown below.  This does *not* work and produces **`PathError`** when I check the status.

```
<UserControl>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource BusinessObject}}">
    <ListBox x:Name="DocumentDisplay" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ContainerStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding Instance.ActiveDocument, Path=Paragraphs}" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I've checked in the C# code-behind and verified the following:

1. The DataContext is correct and non-null.
2. The property is set and also non-null.

However, I *am* able to successfully create the binding using C#:

```
    var dogPargBinding = new Binding() { Source = BusinessObjectClass.Instance.ActiveDocument, Path = new PropertyPath("Paragraphs") };
    this.DocumentDisplay.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, dogPargBinding);
```

Even though this works, I'd like the binding to work from XAML, because much of our development is done through Expression Blend.

Some more details about our implementation:

1. Just to reiterate, this same patten has worked in numerous other locations in the code.
2. ActiveDocument is a dependency property of the BusinessObjectClass, and it is set from a multi-binding created in the C# code-behind.  Testing shows this property is set correctly.

I'm sure there is a simple explanation for what we're doing wrong, but it's getting to the point where it's time to ask.  Thanks in advance.

=============================================================================

I finally found the problem I was having.  The DependencyProperty was being declared with the wrong owner class type.  That screwed up everything, and nothing VS did led me to the answer quickly.

The most helpful answer was one that got deleted... :(

Comment: The error is that the binding status is PathError after setting it to the ListBox.

Answer (score 2):

Your Binding is incorrect. You have `{Binding Instance.ActiveDocument, Path=Paragraphs}`, which is effectively setting the Path property twice.

The `Instance.ActiveDocument` part doesn't specify a property before it, so it will use [this Binding constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597578.aspx), which sets the path of the binding.

Then you set the Path property, effectively overwriting the value passed to the constructor.

I think you mean to use `{Binding Path=Instance.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs}`. Since your DataContext is an instance of `BusinessObjectClass`, this path will look for the Instance property on it. Then it will look for the ActiveDocument property on the object returned from the Instance property. And finally, look for the Paragraphs property on the object returned from the ActiveDocument property.

Comment: Thanks, that does help clear up some confusion I was having.  I don't understand what rules WPF uses for evaluating what is the Source and what is the Path, which I specify explicitly in code but seem to be done "for me" implicitly in XAML.

Comment: @dythim - By default, a Binding will use the DataContext of the associated object (if any). Otherwise, you can specify another "source" using Source or ElementName properties. The problem with your XAML is you don't set the Source property, but you do in your code-behind. Additionally, you can't really set the Source property based on the DataContext. But since you can access the properties directly, you shouldn't need to.